# Find missing numbers with SQL

Tags: sql

In a large log file I have records containing the field INVNO (invoice-number). 
The lowest and highest values are easy to find, BUT it looks like some 
numbers in between are not there. 
Anyone got a trick with SQL, which can tell which numbers are missing within the number range?

Comment: You could try doing it in Excel: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1054-excel-identify-missing-numbers-sequence.html

Comment: At the minimum, edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: If your data is contained in a log file, why are your trying to do that using SQL?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following table valued function that takes 2 parameters : the min and max numbers,
and returns a list of missing number,
suppose your table name is YOUR_TABLE and the column name called InvNo

```
    create FUNCTION [dbo].[MissingInvoiceNumbers]
(
   @minPaym bigint,
   @MaxPaym bigint
)
RETURNS @tmp table(numbers bigint)

AS


BEGIN
declare  @n bigint --@minPaym bigint , @MaxPaym bigint,
declare @tmpAll table(Allnumbers bigint)

set @n= @minPaym
delete @tmp
delete @tmpAll

while (@n<=@MaxPaym)
begin
INSERT INTO @tmpAll
                      (AllNUMBERS)
VALUES     (@n)
set @n=@n+1
end

INSERT INTO @tmp
                      (numbers)
SELECT     Allnumbers
FROM         @tmpAll
where Allnumbers not in (select distinct convert(bigint,InvNo) as InvoiceNum  from YOUR_TABLE where 
InvNo <> '' )

return 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

For oracle this should work. For any other database you just need to change way to generate the number sequence.

```
with vals as (
  select rownum r
  from dual
connect by rownum between {min} and {max}
)

select *
from vals v
left join {sometable} s on s.{someid} = v.r
where s.{someid} is null
```

The trick is just to generate numbers between min and max value, join table with invoices to this generated sequence and filter out everything that match.

Answer (score -1):

Just join the table on itself...

```
DECLARE @tvp TABLE ( INVNO INT )
INSERT  INTO @tvp
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 5 ),
        ( 6 ),
        ( 7 ),
        ( 8 ),
        ( 9 ),
        ( 10 ),
        ( 11 )

SELECT  *
FROM    @tvp;


SELECT t.INVNO + 1
FROM    @tvp t
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @tvp x ON x.INVNO = t.INVNO + 1
WHERE   ISNULL(x.INVNO, 0) = 0;
```